# is it possible to make order by clause using index in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Now I am using this command to query in MySQL 5.7:

```
       SELECT max(user_name) AS user_name, 
    user_id AS user_id, 
    max(login_name) AS login_name, 
    max(nick_name) AS nick_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(app_name) AS app_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(app_mark) AS app_mark_concat, 
    sum(gain) AS gain, 
    sum(room_reward + expect_reward) AS room_reward, 
    sum(platform_profit) AS platform_profit, 
    sum(room_count) AS room_count, 
    sum(room_create_count) AS room_create_count, 
    sum(invite_count) AS invite_count, 
    sum(temp_room_count) AS temp_room_count, 
    CASE WHEN sum(online_status) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS online_status,
 max(account_create_time) AS account_create_time, 
    max(latest_login_time) AS latest_login_time, 
    max(first_login_device) AS first_login_device, 
    sum(total_spent) AS total_spent, 
    sum(total_gain) AS total_gain, 
    sum(trans_into_count) AS trans_into_count, 
    sum(trans_out_count) AS trans_out_count, 
    sum(trans_into_amount) AS trans_into_amount, 
    sum(trans_out_amount) AS trans_out_amount, 
    max(status) AS status, 
    max(current_login_device) AS current_login_device, max(current_login_device_name) AS current_login_device_name, max(registered_time) AS registered_time, 
    avg(is_user_logined) AS is_user_logined, 
    sum(round_count) AS round_count, 
    avg(wallet_remain_count) AS wallet_remain_count, 
    max(ip_location) AS ip_location, 
    max(lastest_login_ip) AS lastest_login_ip, 
    sum(entry_app_count) AS entry_app_count, 
    sum(entry_house_count) AS entry_house_count, 
    sum(entry_room_count) AS entry_room_count 
    FROM report_user 
    WHERE report_user.tenant_id = 1 
    GROUP BY user_id, statistic_date  
        ORDER BY registered_time DESC
        LIMIT 10
```

when I am not using `ORDER BY registered_time DESD`  clause, the query response very fast, but when I add the order by clause, the query could not reponse. there have 400000 lines in my table.This is the index I am created now:

```
CREATE INDEX report_user_userid_staticdate_idx 
ON report_user
(
    user_id,
    statistic_date,
    registered_time,
    tenant_id,
    is_user_logined
);
```

this is the table DML:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_user` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '主键',
  `app_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '应用名称',
  `app_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '应用ID',
  `app_mark` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '应用标识',
  `created_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '创建时间',
  `updated_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '更新时间',
  `creator` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '创建者',
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '排序',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '是否删除',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '状态（1:正常 -1:锁定）',
  `online_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '在线状态（0:离线 1:在线）',
  `room_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '创建的普通房间数',
  `room_create_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '创建的普通房间数次数',
  `invite_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '拉新人数',
  `temp_room_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '临时房间次数',
  `latest_login_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '最后登陆时间',
  `latest_active_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '最后活跃时间',
  `first_login_device` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '1.IOS 2:Android 3.H5 4:PC',
  `current_login_device` int(11) DEFAULT '-1' COMMENT '1.IOS 2:Android 3.H5 4:PC',
  `current_login_device_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '设备名称',
  `account_create_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '账户创建时间',
  `wallet_remain_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '游戏钱包余额',
  `trans_into_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转入次数',
  `trans_out_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转出次数',
  `trans_into_amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转入金额',
  `trans_out_amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转出金额',
  `user_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '用户名',
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '用户ID',
  `nick_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '用户昵称',
  `login_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '用户登录名',
  `back_money` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '金额',
  `registered_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '注册时间',
  `tenant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '租户ID',
  `effective_bets` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '有效',
  `is_user_logined` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '用户是否登录过系统',
  `round_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '玩游戏的局数',
  `lastest_login_ip` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '最后一次登录IP',
  `ip_location` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'IP所属地址',
  `entry_app_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '进入过的游戏数（进入游戏房间才算数）',
  `statistic_time` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '统计时间',
  `gain` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_house_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '进入大厅次数',
  `entry_room_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '进入房间次数',
  `statistic_date` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_format(from_unixtime((`statistic_time` / 1000)),'%Y-%m-%d')) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`app_id`,`statistic_time`),
  KEY `report_user_userid_staticdate_idx` (`user_id`,`statistic_date`,`registered_time`,`tenant_id`,`is_user_logined`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=439939 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin COMMENT='提转统计';
```

what should I do to speed up this query again? each user with multi lines of app.

Comment: Create index by `(tenant_id, user_id, statistic_date, registered_time)`. But (with partial GROUP BY) your query is not deterministic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there one row per "user"?  Or many?  If only one, then shouldn't `user_id` be the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If many, shouldn't the `user_name` (and many other columns) be moved to another table?  That is, split this table into two tables:

```
users, with PRIMARY KEY(user_id)

user_logins
```

And make them 1:many.  (That is, one user to many logins.)

Once you have fixed that, we can address your original question.

To optimize...  Turn the query inside-out.  That is, *start* by finding the ids for the 10 items you want, *then* do the summation.  That will significantly shrink the amount of work to be done.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT userid, statistic_date FROM ... 
               WHERE ...
               ORDER BY ...
               LIMIT 10 ) AS x
    JOIN report_user USING(userid, statistic_date)
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...
```

Once you have that written and working, I'll help you make the optimal index.

Comment: many row with user@Rick James

Comment: @Dolphin - I added a tip for speeding it up.  But please split the table first (if that suggestion is also relevant).